# I have get error [__NSArrayI objectForKeyedSubscript:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays

```
[self.arrEmail removeAllObjects];
self.arrEmail = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
for (NSDictionary *object in [dictionary valueForKey:@"heroes"]) {
    NSString *objectName = object[@"user_email"];
    [self.arrEmail addObject:objectName];
}
```

My application is crashing at these lines of code. Xcode says

```
[__NSArrayI objectForKeyedSubscript:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance.
```

Can any one help?

Comment: Your code ends up subscripting an array with a key (as if it were a dictionary). The only code in your question that does that is `object[@"user_email"]`. Could you print the full contents of `[dictionary valueForKey:@"heroes"]`?

Comment: `object` seems to be an `NSArray`, not a `NSDictionary` as your code suggest.

Comment: @DavidRönnqvist Thanks, Its working fine

Comment: @Larme Thanks you too